# How to call JavaScript from Mono's WebKitSharp?

Tags: .net, mono, webkit, gtk#

I tried [this](http://shana.worldofcoding.com/en/browser.html) code. All works, but I can't find a way to reach the DOM or to call JavaScript from it. Any ideas how to do that? This is using GTK# and WebKitSharp.

EDIT: Also I need to get the result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
webView.ExecuteScript("alert('An alert from C#!');");
```

will do the trick.

Getting the results back is another challange though: WebKit.DOMDocument is not implemented in webkit-sharp, so you can't access the DOM. There are a few workarounds, this is what we normally do:

- Have a invisible frame somwhere in your page
- Get the WebFrame for it via `webView.MainFrame.FindFrame("framename")`
- in your JS write your result to the title of this invisible frame
- use `myWebFrame.Title` to read it from C#

Comment: Thanks. But how to get the result?

Comment: I know this is hacky, but I am unable to fix the underlying cause: Missing DOM access in webkit-sharp

Comment: Hello again, I saw that this trick doesn't work with the current WebKitSharp. What version do you use?

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? I use webkit-sharp 0.3 with a few (unrelated) patches

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And how can I call C# function from JS(e.g. for interception onclick events)? You can also check [my question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35576038/html-ui-using-webkit). Regards.