# How to write a simple browser with DOM access?

Tags: linux, dom

What is an easy way to write a browser application on Linux (Crunchbang/Debian)?

I need to write an application for some DOM editing and automation. My preferred way of doing this is to have my own browser object (like WebKit's WebView or System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser) and access the DOM from there.  I tried both (with mono), but I found two things:

1. WebView does not implement DOM access ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9804360/how-to-call-javascript-from-monos-webkitsharp))
2. System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser does not work ([ref](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Simple-example-of-Gtk-based-Mono-WebBrowser-on-Windows-Mac-td4658539.html))

This means Mono is not very suitable for this purpose.
What is your preferred way for accessing web pages, reading the DOM and automating navigation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably easier to use PhantomJS?

Uses Webkit to render webpages and then makes the DOM available for you:

http://phantomjs.org